# ACL and LDAP configuration warning?

Tags: ldap, acl, openldap

I have the following error happen when I try to use `ldapsearch`

`ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)`

I then see the following output when I debug using the `slapd` command for LDAP

```
58c1b1fa /etc/openldap/slapd.d: line 1: warning: cannot assess the validity of the ACL scope within backend naming context
```

Since I am using LDAP 2.4 I thus have to use the LDIF file which contains the following:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}monitor,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth"
  read by dn.base="cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=com" read by * none

dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcSuffix
olcSuffix: dc=domain,dc=com

dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=com

dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: pass

dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by
  dn="cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=com" write by anonymous auth by self write by * none
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: {2}to * by dn="cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=com" write by * read
```

Is my LDIF file causing this ACL error to happen, and if so how can I fix it, if not what is then causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your ldif is probably fine but we'd need to see it to be sure. A 49 is an invalid password. Check the user DN and password

Comment: I inserted the LDIF file that I used, also I know it means an invalid password however I am able to login fine with the password through `phpldapadmin`

Comment: That's the whole thing? For some reason I thought there'd be more. How are you trying to import it, what command?

Comment: well I followed this exactly https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_6&p=ldap so maybe that will give you a better idea of what I did